# OpenCV image matching (regardless of color)

Tags: java, opencv

I am kind of hopeless in my quest to write a screenshot reader for a game I am addicted to.
We take a screenshot, regardless of size/coloring (so custom settings ingame) and I have a library of images I want to check it against. I am using OpenCV
Example screenshot:
[image: Inventory]
now I have a library of all ingame materials, for example this one
[image: item]
I already know how to rescale and stuffs, but I just know too little for it to find a decent match. I am quite new in image filtering/matching and such so if you have any ideas/tipps, please let me know. My code so far:

```
    public void scan2( String image, String template ) {
    Mat iterateImg = Imgcodecs.imread(image, Imgcodecs.IMREAD_COLOR);
    Mat templ2 = Imgcodecs.imread(template, Imgcodecs.IMREAD_COLOR);
    Mat templ2resized = new Mat();
    double templx = templ2.size().width;
    double temply = templ2.size().height;
    System.out.println(templx+"-"+temply);
    for(double scale = 1;scale <2;scale = scale+0.01 ){
        Imgproc.resize(templ2, templ2resized, new Size(templx/scale, temply/scale));
        MatchResultWrapper match = match(iterateImg, templ2resized);
        match.setScaledx((int) (templx/scale));
        match.setScaledy((int) (temply/scale));

        vals.add(match);

    }
    double[]results= new double[vals.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i < vals.size();i++){
        results[i]=vals.get(i).getMatch();
    }
    double diff = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int closestIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < results.length; ++i) {
        double abs = Math.abs(results[i]);
        if (abs < diff) {
            closestIndex = i;
            diff = abs;
        } else if (abs == diff && results[i] > 0 && results[closestIndex] < 0) {
            //same distance to zero but positive
            closestIndex =i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(vals.get(closestIndex));
}


private MatchResultWrapper match( Mat source, Mat template ) {
    Mat result = new Mat();
    Mat img_display = new Mat();
    source.copyTo(img_display);
    int result_cols = source.cols() - template.cols() + 1;
    int result_rows = source.rows() - template.rows() + 1;
    result.create(result_rows, result_cols, CvType.CV_32FC1);
    Imgproc.matchTemplate(source, template, result, Imgproc.TM_SQDIFF);
    Core.normalize(result, result, 0, 1, Core.NORM_MINMAX, - 1, new Mat());
    Core.MinMaxLocResult mmr = Core.minMaxLoc(result);
    MatchResultWrapper wrapper = new MatchResultWrapper();
    wrapper.setMatch(mmr.minVal);
    wrapper.setX((int)mmr.minLoc.x);
    wrapper.setY((int)mmr.minLoc.y);

    return wrapper;
}
```

Thanks to @christoph-rackwitz we now have the following result. Which sadly does not work either :( [image: Laplacian Filter]

Comment: run a laplacian filter, then convert to gray, or first convert and then filter. then you are left with only edges, not levels.

Comment: Added that, doesn't appear to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need a mask for your template. For template matching, the [match mode documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/df/dfb/group__imgproc__object.html#ga3a7850640f1fe1f58fe91a2d7583695d) is not 100% clear. But `TM_SQDIFF`, `TM_SQDIFF_NORMED`, `TM_CCORR`, and `TM_CCORR_NORMED` seem to support masks. I generally prefer the normed match modes, but you can try both of these modes to see what gives you best results. If you do try `TM_CCORR_NORMED` be sure to use max instead of min.